# Basic RoR Webmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webmail

I am attempting to build a really basic RoR webmail application, I have done some research and found the following opensource: mailyt and mailr
However these are roughly 4 and 3 years old respectively.

What are the potential pitfalls of using code that is significantly out of date? Would it be better for me to just create my own project from scratch?

Alternatively does anybody know of a more recent open source RoR webmail project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you wanted to build your own webmail application. Mailyt and mailr are webmail applications. So I assume you want to reuse some of their code for your own project.

If you want to build your webmail application in Rails now I think you should use the newest stable version of Rails, because of new features, security and performance improvements and because older versions of Rails will stop being maintained and upgrading will get increasingly harder over time.

If you want to reuse code from older Rails versions it might just not work, because the Rails-API has changed. You can get an idea which specifics have changed here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html depending on which Rails versions you're dealing with.

I would write the app from scratch for the learning effects, but I think it will be faster to adjust the code to suite your project than writing everything from scratch. Incompatible code from older Rails versions will most likely just throw an exception. Be sure to have an extensive test suite for your project though. Especially if you're using someone else's code.